# Filter Array Liquid in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have an include which renders my posts in a certain format. I am passing the posts to the include like below:

`{% include post-list.html posts=site.posts %}`

However, I would like to filter out a certain category before passing it to the include. Does anyone have any ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it defining a variable containing an array with all the posts not containing a specific category and then passing that to includes, for example to filter posts containing the category `jekyll`:

1. We create the array `{% assign notjekyllposts = "" | split: "" %}`
2. Loop all posts `{% for apost in site.posts %}`
3. Filter those that does not contain the `jekyll` category adding them to the array: 
    `{% assign notjekyllposts = notjekyllposts | push: apost %}`
4. Pass the variable to the `include` tag

Putting it all together:

```
{% assign notjekyllposts = "" | split: "" %}

{% for apost in site.posts %}
  {% unless apost.categories contains 'jekyll' %}
    {% assign notjekyllposts = notjekyllposts | push: apost %}
  {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
{% include post-list.html posts=notjekyllposts %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I would like to filter out a category. Or remove all posts of a certain category out of the array.